# MYSQL can't select dates

Tags: mysql

I have just dumped my database and restored to a different server. It was on Amazon RDS and is now a local VM.

None of my selects work any more.

```
select * from losses where date_selected = "2016-05-18";
```

**This works on my live Amazon server but not my new local development server.**

Surely this is just a regional setting?

```
SELECT @@system_time_zone;
```

Gives BST but on the Amazon box it gives UTC

Mick

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
id  int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI     auto_increment
created_at  timestamp   NO      0000-00-00 00:00:00 
updated_at  timestamp   NO      0000-00-00 00:00:00 
deleted_at  timestamp   YES         
product_id  int(10) unsigned    NO  MUL     
date_selected   timestamp   NO      0000-00-00 00:00:00 


id  created_at  updated_at  deleted_at  product_id  date_selected
33611   18/05/2016 13:40:09 18/05/2016 13:40:09     99143   18/05/2016 01:00:00
33648   18/05/2016 16:47:16 18/05/2016 16:47:16     108218  18/05/2016 01:00:00
33651   18/05/2016 16:48:58 18/05/2016 16:48:58     100368  18/05/2016 01:00:00
```

Note:

**This works on my live Amazon server but not my new local development server.**

So, unless you can tell me how to get this query working without changing it, don't bother replying.

Comment: Try using a mysql formatted date string in your where statement e.g: ``where date_selected =  '2016-05-18';``

Comment: Sorry, tried that originally.

Comment: Add table structure & example data

Comment: date_selected is time stamp, and time stamp looks like this, `1463664824 ` while your are using `2016-05-15` in your query. Therefore not selecting dates.

Comment: Why does it work on my other server then?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using timestamps I think your query should look like this

```
select * from losses where DATE(date_selected) = "2016-05-18";
```

Comment: That works, but I don't want to change my code which is working on my live server.

Comment: The issue here is that timestamp stores date & time; but you want to compare the date only. If all your data have a time of ``01:00:00`` as shown in your query, then you can use that time with your queries without casting the field to date only

Comment: On my other server the data shows: 18/05/2016 01:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Could be you have date to str conversion issue

```
  select * from losses where str_to_date(date_selected, '%Y-%m-%d') = "2016-05-18";
```

Comment: That works, but I don't want to change my code which is working on my live server.

Comment: Based on your schema i don't see other way .. you have timestamp and you are matching a string .. you can do the inverse but this mean the same  ..

Comment: So, why does: select * from losses where date_selected = "2016-05-18"; work on my live server where I won't be changing my code.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the datatype from timestamp to date on my development server and this now works correctly.

Nobody could ever explain why this select worked on my live Amazon server.